# Parse iOS SDK 1.8.5 causes try throw & PFObject conditional cast errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

After updating to the latest Parse SDK 1.8.5, I am receiving two errors surrounding the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` function. Two errors return on the same line:

```
if let objects = query.findObjects() as? [PFObject]
```

I have tried changing it to `as [PFObject]?` with no luck. The errors are as follows:

`Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled` 
AND `Conditional cast from '[PFObject]' to '[PFObject]' always succeeds`

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if error == nil {

   if let objects = query.findObjects() as? [PFObject] {

       for object in objects {

           object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock{ (success, error) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                     print("Worked")
                     print(objects.count)
                     self.viewDidAppear(true)

                } else {
           }
       }
```

I have researched similar problems, and tried to fix it to `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in` but this has done nothing either.

I am not sure how to fix either of these errors, and am very confused as to why they suddenly popped up. All of my functions were running perfectly, and have been for weeks, and suddenly these errors have popped up.

changing it from:

```
if let objects = query.findObjects() as? [PFObject]
```

to

```
if let objects = objects as [PFObject]?
```

seemed to fix the problem, but I am not sure if it is now going to run properly.

For other lines with the same error, XCode suggested changing it to:

```
self.rooms = (results as [PFObject]?)!
```

and that took away the error. I am pretty new to Swift coding, so I am not sure exactly what has happened, if anyone has any insight?

Answer (score 2):

Using `findObjects()` is much more difficult with the new update. This is because with Xcode 7 and Swift 2, Swift became better at handling errors and Parse took advantage of these new methods to allow `findObjects()` to throw an error. It would be your job to handle the error and provide other code to run in case of such an error. In addition to these new requirements, `findObjects()` runs synchronously and will slow down your app. You should be using `findObjectsInBackground()` which runs asynchronously. This will solve both of your problems. If you need hep implementing this function, there is a lot of documentation and question/answers online.

Comment: I took out the query.findObjects and made it this, as it states everywhere online:  `if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]` but that does not fix the problem. The error:  `Downcast from '[PFObject]?' to '[PFObject]' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?` still appears.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. Can you post a little more of the code so I have some context? In addition, have you tried what the complier suggests?

Comment: I added some more code and information about what I tried.

Comment: Why are you trying to cast `objects` to an array of `PFObjects`? It already is an array. Just leave it as is.

Comment: That is what is says to do on the Parse documentation? `if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]` is copied from the docs.

Comment: I read the docs again and saw that indeed, you are correct. I am not able to test any suggestions right now, but I still think that it is unnecessary to cast objects to [PFObject]. I think that this may be left over from previous versions of parse, where objects would have been [AnyObject] and would therefore have to be cast to [PFObject].

Answer (score 0):

Removing `as [PFObject]?` from `if let objects = objects as [PFObject]?` should solve your conditional cast error.